# Bootstrap4 radio form has a bug

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to make a form to have radio, but it has a problem. When I choose radio choice in the first form then I choose radio choice in the second form radio in first form miss.

Code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>เคยเป็นลูกค้าของ</label> <a href="https://jobbkk.com/">JOBBKK.com</a>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">เคย</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">ไม่เคย</label>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>เคยใช้บริการ Recruitment Service</label> 
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio3" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input" required>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio3">เคย</label>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio4" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input" required>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio4">ไม่เคย</label>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1040347) of text. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, [paste the code as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have different values for names.

The ID of a form input element has nothing to do with the data contained within the element.

- `id` is used for hooking the element with JavaScript and CSS.
- `name` attribute, however, is used in the HTTP request sent by your browser to the server as a variable name associated with the data contained in the value attribute.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html ch 17.4